# Riemannian metric on fixed rank manifold

Tags: metric-spaces, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, machine-learning, sampling

I know that one can define metrics on the manifold of SPD matrices

$$
\mathcal{S}^n =  \{ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \ | \ \text{A positive semi-definite} \}
$$

like the Log-Euclidean metric or the Riemannian Affine invariant metric (AIRM) that capture the geometry of the underlying manifold better than the standard Euclidean metric (see for example [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11263-005-3222-z)).

I am interested in a Riemannian metric on the fixed-rank manifold

$$
\mathcal{M}_k =  \{ X \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} \ | \ \text{rank}(X) = k \},
$$

that captures the geometry of the manifold and is also computationally accessible.

Does anybody know something? I would appreciate any help!

Comment: You have to list some properties that your metric should satisfy, otherwise your question is impossible to answer as there are way too many metrics on this manifold.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am not bound to certain properties. At this stage, I would only need a metric that captures the structure of the manifold and can be computed in an easy manner. Also, recommendations how I can approach the topic would help me a lot.